# ouputs repeating in foreach loop in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a php file where i am trying to fetch values from database and show in the web page. I have written a foreach loop but it is showing same output for several times. here is my code

```
<?php
session_start();
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pass="";
    $db="documentation";

    $off=$_GET['id'];
    $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT category_name FROM category WHERE id='$off'");
    $rslt=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $query1=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT cat_description FROM category WHERE id='$off'");
    $rslt1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);
    $shown=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT b.subcat_name, b.id, b.description
        FROM category a, subcategory b
        WHERE b.cat_name = (SELECT category_name FROM category WHERE id='$off')");





?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Category</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
foreach ($shown as $showsubn) { ?>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<p class="border1">
<p class="margin">
<i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
<a href="subcat.php?id=<?php echo $showsubn['id']; ?>"><font size="4"><?php  implode(" ",$showsubn); echo $showsubn['subcat_name'];?> </font></a>
<p class="margin"><?php  implode(" ",$showsubn); echo $showsubn['description'];?></p>
</p>
    </p>
    <p class="border4"></p>
</div>

</div>
<?php
    }; ?>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the output should be 
canbangla
youbangla

but it is showing 
canbangla
canbangla
canbangla
...upto 12 several times
youbangla
youbangla
youbangla
...upto 12 several times

Comment: got my solution 
used DISTINCT in my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding [DISTINCT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html) operator to your query?

You can use it like:

```
$shown=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT b.subcat_name, b.id, b.description
        FROM category a, subcategory b
        WHERE b.cat_name = (SELECT category_name FROM category WHERE id='$off')");
```

Distinct operator displays the unique data depending on which column you chose

Answer (score 1):

change

```
foreach ($shown as $showsubn) {
```

to

```
while ($showsubn = mysqli_fetch_assoc($shown))
```

Comment: Maybe you want to explain *why* OP has to change the code like this.

Comment: @Rizier123 Sorry, I am not sure why it works; I just know it works. Maybe someone with enough expertise can answer the 'why'.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
while ($showsubn = mysqli_fetch_assoc($shown))
```

Instead of

```
foreach ($shown as $showsubn)
```

Hope this will solve your issue

Comment: Maybe you want to explain *why* OP has to change the code like this.

Comment: thanks for the help. I used DISTINCT operator in my query and that solved my problem....

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```
<?php

while($showsubn = mysqli_fetch_assoc($shown))
{
?>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<p class="border1">
<p class="margin">
<i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
<a href="subcat.php?id=<?php echo $showsubn['id']; ?>"><font size="4"><?php  implode(" ",$showsubn); echo $showsubn['subcat_name'];?> </font></a>
<p class="margin"><?php  implode(" ",$showsubn); echo $showsubn['description'];?></p>
</p>
    </p>
    <p class="border4"></p>
</div>

</div>

<?php } 
?>
```

It will work perfectly.

Comment: thanks for the help
I used DISTINCT operator in my query and that solved my problem....